# Runtime Error for U-SQL Scripts when Repeatedly Executing in Local Environment

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

We have a simple U-SQL Migration Script that:

1. Selects data from a staging table in our ADL database
2. Truncates the staging table
3. Inserts contents to a persisted table in ADL

When we run this script after running our loading script for our staging table, the script runs successfully and the data is inserted. If I run this same migration script for a second time, however, I get the following error:

> "diagnosticCode":195887168,"severity":"Error","component":"RUNTIME","source":"System","errorId":"E_RUNTIME_SYSTEM_INTERNALISSUE","message":"An
>   internal error has been reported [**Assertion failed:
>   'partitionDimension < vertexIndices.size()'** at
>   ScopeEngine::GetPartitionIndex(1020),]"

Finally, if I again run the loading script followed by the migration script, all is well again. Can anyone provide more information about what may be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rebuild the script before run the second time if the input data changes.  There's a limitation in the current local build process, we don't detected input data changes.

The script compilation results depend on input data.  If the data changes, we need to recompile the script to generate the correct code.